# Angular 8 canActivate on refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Im trying to use `canActivate` (which I've been using for the past 2 years) on angular 8 and I cant seem to make it work.

on refresh/f5 I don't even see the request on the network, and when it goes inside the response it gives me "cannot read property length of undefined"

Here is the code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  const user = this.cookieSerivce.getUserCookie();
  if (!this.userService.getUserIfExists().Authorization && user) {
    this.userService.setUser(user);
  }

  return this.usersEndpointService.validateUserToken().pipe(
    map((res) => {
      if (!res.code) return true;

      this.wrongToken();
      return false;
    },
  }));
}

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [ValidTokenService]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

What am I missing?
I know for sure it does not even send the request, not seeing it on the network and not getting it on the backend, why?

Comment: Can you also show us the route definitions which use this Guard? Also, did you add console-outputs or a debugging statement inside the `canActivate` method to make sure it is being called properly?

Comment: @PhilippMeissner I added, and Also, I know for sure i`m debuging both on server and ui.
its not sending the request.